# How can I index a generic with an with the argument passed in to function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose I have an interface in typescript as follows:

```js
interface I1 {
    name: string,
    age: number
}
```

And I have another interface that accesses interface properties:

```js
interface I2<T> {
    getValue: (arg0: keyof T) => any
}
```

I want to be able to pass in another interface into I2 such that you can only pass in keys of T and it will return the type of that key.

So If I have

```js
const record: I2<I1> = new Record()
```

I want

```js
const name = record.getValue('name')
```

to return a string and

```js
const age = record.getValue('age')
```

to return a number

The first part works - I can only pass in keys of `I1`
The second part doesn't work.

I tried

```js
interface I2<T> {
    getValue: (arg0: keyof T) => T[keyof T]
}
```

but this makes that any call to `getValue` will return a union `number|string`.

I tried

```js
interface I2<T> {
    getValue: (arg0: keyof T) => T[arg0]
}
```

but this isn't valid typescript

Comment: You need `getValue()` to be a generic method as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WzkdLw).  Does that meet your needs? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: `new Record` is some javascript class that will implement `I2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `getValue()` to represent a relationship between the particular key input and the type of the output, you'll need to make it a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) method with its own type parameter `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof T`, like this:

```
interface I2<T> {
    getValue: <K extends keyof T>(k: K) => T[K]
}
```

Now things should behave as expected:

```
interface I1 {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

declare const record: I2<I1>;

const name = record.getValue('name')
// const name: string
const age = record.getValue('age');
// const age: number
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAVQOYAsUG9jApEoCWIALlAE4BmSqAkgEwA8AKgHx6HG8ZTkAamAA2AVygAuFCwDSKKAA9KIACYwUAaygBPAPY0UnABSbpsgJQoAvFzYBtWQF0eRAL4FeZSrXooGAIzcvLzg0NIw5FRkGAA0riFg-NIgYhAARtQJHgmqUIgiYFSoiHogkSjFpVSq0swsgRwA3J7EpeXkKGGo1pX5ejUAdPxCohLGAOTdExYJAPRzKO0V3RFRMQnLnUk9fdWqwwLC4lCTOzMtvAtLZRU7KWmZVARuQA)